# Change type of object based on typeof another object

Tags: r

How do I change the `typeof` of one object `a` to another object `b`
without explicitly specifying the type

```r
a <- letters
b <- as.factor(a)

typeof(a)
#> [1] "character"
```

So I would like to convert b to `typeof(a)`, but without explicitly
using `as.character`, because in another instance `a` might be e.g.
`integer`. This obviously does not work:

```r
typeof(b) <- typeof(a)
```

Comment: The closest i could come: 
`a <- '1';

b <- 2;

lapply(a,paste0('as.',class(b)))

`

Comment: "b" has an explicit class while "a" does not. It does not generally make sense to change the `typeof` of an object with class with the `typeof` of an object without. What should happen with the attributes (including "class") of "b"? `factor` objects have (or have not) specific methods to coerce (here, `as.character.factor`) that, in this particular case, seems to simply coerce to a "character" but other methods may not behave as expected/wanted when coercing an object with a class to imitate the `typeof` of an object without class. For simpler cases, see `storage.mode(b) = storage.mode(a)`

Answer (score 2):

The closest I could come is, but not sure if there's any better solution.

```
a <- '1'

b <- 2

a <- unlist(lapply(a,paste0('as.',class(b))))

a

a <- '245'

a <- unlist(lapply(a,paste0('as.',class(b))))

a

Output:
> a
[1] 245
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer to @amrrs except I think you may want this functionality to be used programtically, and when converting types of an object you may get errors that return `NA`'s - which is unwanted behaviour - when you try and convert variables that cannot be coerced to another data type.

The below function accounts for this based on R's coercion rules. (Assuming you want to be using `class()` and not `typeof()`)

```
convertClass <- function(object1, object2){
  logic=c("logical", "integer", "numeric", "complex", "character", "list")

  ifelse(match(class(object1), logic) < match(class(object2), logic),
         eval(parse(text=paste0('as.',class(object2),"(",object1,")"))),
         paste0("convertClass() cannot convert type ", class(object1), " to ", class(object2))
    )
  }

> convertClass(1,'1')
[1] "1"
> convertClass('1', 1)
[1] "convertClass() cannot convert type character to numeric"
```

Using this loses the functionality of converting `"1"` to `1` for example, which can be coerced in `R`, but does provide a strict safeguard if you don't know the type of a variable that you are feeding the function.